# What happens when two PHP scripts are executed at same moment

Tags: php

Assuming I’ve the following code

```
$num = get_file('number.txt'); // number.txt is zero 
// Here User #2 will enter
$num = $num + $_POST['add'];
save_file($num,'number.txt') // saving changes
```

Simply, User #1 will send through `POST` an integer value: `7`.

While the script is being executed for user 1: **After getting the document** and **before saving it**, User #2 send through `POST` an integer value: `8`

It’s one of two:

- php won’t execute the script for user #2 before it was finished for
  user #1 thus we will get a value of 15 (7+8) saved in number.txt
- php will multi handle both requests thus $num will be zero for both users. Thus the final value in number.txt will be the latest change which is done by user #2 i.e it will be “8”.

I don’t know any tools to test such atomic operations, so i might be missing something.

I am confused about would the final value in `number.txt` be “8” or “15”.

If the value is ”8”, what is a solution if I’m expecting it to be ”15”

Comment: "php won’t execute the script for user #2 before it was finished for user #1 thus we will get a value of 15 (7+8) saved in number.txt" <-- This won't happen except in single-threaded in-proc PHP environments, which I don't think exist anymore...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read and write to a file while keeping lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450850/read-and-write-to-a-file-while-keeping-lock)

Comment: Yes, and I got the answer from Jens eariler! Thank yoy.

Comment: If you put `sleep(30);` at some strategic point in your test script you can easily simulate race conditions emitting two requests in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your web-sever executes the PHP code in separate threads at the same time, what you’re looking at is the [parallel processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing#Race_conditions,_mutual_exclusion,_synchronization,_and_parallel_slowdown) of the same task with a single shared resource (your file `number.txt`). The scenario you describe is called a [data race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Data_race). In that case you need to take extra care of the [data synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)#Thread_or_process_synchronization) — in PHP for example using a [mutex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.syncmutex.php).

Take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056690/how-to-avoid-race-hazard-with-multiple-requests).

Comment: Just curious. Is [`flock`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)  useful in this case?

Comment: @nice_dev I figured out that SleekDB uses it, which is NoSQL DB. I could see that it locks the file on reading and writing. I will probably use that code, as it’s good optimised.